# How to intercept FlightRecording events ( java )?

Tags: java, jmc, jfr

Is there a way to intercept FlightRecorder events in order to send them not only into FlightRecording during recording but to another consumer also.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to hack an aircraft :). Your question is not giving a bit of hint on what are your trying to do. Rephrase it and include what you have tried.

Comment: For me question is preatty staight. Anyway the point is to gather metrics from application to create a kind of _my-own_ report about app's state and to send it to external info consumer.

Comment: For now, I've only tried to create my own event, but had no success in searching for in using JMC...

Answer (score 0):

No, event data is copied to a thread local buffer. There is no way to intercept.